# How animate DataTemplate on Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I need to animate the content on CollectionView 
the Header and The items.

I have used the DataTemplate for both.

Any sugestion ?

Comment: What do you need to animate inside your templates ?

Comment: What's the problem you're encountering?

Comment: was impossible to access the views inside the data template using x:Name, but I have found a solution, using custom control inside the dataTemplate    and binding the object <control:LabelOperazione Operazione="{Binding .}" />